# Django query many objects in many

Tags: python, django, model

Is there a query way of doing the following in Django models like joining in SQL?

```
result = []
for f in self.Functions.all():
    result = result + list(f.Properties.all())
return result
```

where `self` is a `Device` object

Models

```
class Property(models.Model):
    Id = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, primary_key=True, blank=False, editable=False)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Parameters = jsonfield.JSONField(default="{}")
    Value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Type = models.IntegerField(choices=[(choice.value, choice.name.replace("_", " ")) for choice in TypeEnum])
    Class = models.IntegerField(choices=[(choice.value, choice.name.replace("_", " ")) for choice in ClassEnum])
    Comparable = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Function(models.Model):
    Id = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, primary_key=True, blank=False, editable=False)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Properties = models.ManyToManyField(Property, blank=True)

class Device(models.Model):
    Id = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, primary_key=True, blank=False, editable=False)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Parameters = jsonfield.JSONField(default="{}")
    Functions = models.ManyToManyField(Function, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you share the models, how are `Function`s and `Properties` related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this like:

```
result = Properties.objects.filter(function__device=self)
```

So here we `JOIN` with the many-to-many table between `Properties` and `Function`, and on the many-to-many table between `Function` and `Device`.

Comment: I want to fetch each Property records of a Device. This is not using Device. Thanks.

Comment: @LeventKıran: fixed.

Answer (score 0):

By default django already do the joins in lazy mode... so if you need they do... how to use that

With regular ForeignKey (OneToOne or OneToMany Relations)

```
class User(models.Models):
    ...
    attribute1 = models.CharField(max_lenght)

class Person(models.Models):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User)
    attribute2 = models.CharField(max_lenght)

class Student(models.Models):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    attribute3 = models.CharField(max_lenght)

for student in Student.objects.all():
    print(student.attribute3)
    print(student.person.attribute2)
    print(student.person.user.attribute1)
```

So that way you gonna reach all Joins when do that as using foreignkeys

So above just a little bit of information about how django handle things

About your doubt you can do that

```
...
result = []
for f in self.Functions.all():
    [result.append(p) for p in f.Properties.all()]
return result
```

Comment: I don't wanna use a loop to merge Properties of Functions, instead pull them at once by Device